# IONIC cordova google plus plugin not getting full detail except email?

Tags: android, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework, google-plus

I am using [Cordova plugin to login with Google Plus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) on Android not receiving User data except email.

```
window.plugins.googleplus.login(
        {},
        function (user_data) {})
```

It is not provideing following contents

```
obj.userId       
obj.displayName  
obj.imageUrl     
obj.idToken
obj.oauthToken
obj.gender      
obj.givenName    
obj.middleName   
obj.familyName   
obj.birthday    
obj.ageRangeMin  
obj.ageRangeMax
```

result :

```
{email:"exmple@gmail.com"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Comment: The problem is that this plugin must show all data, but only show email                             https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/google-plus-login-with-ionic-framework

Comment: file an issue on the plugin's github page

Comment: ......................................................??